# Gradually incrementing stroke width in java

Tags: java, java-2d

I have to draw the figure on the link in java as an assignment.[The assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNZ3q.png)

So far I have been able to draw the first arc using CubicCurve2D, as seen on the picture on the second link, but now I face the problem of incrementing the line width gradually.[What I have achieved until now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rn8F8.png)

Can anyone tell me if there is any way of achieving it. Thank you!

This is the code for the panel

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
public class GraphicsDemo extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2D.setPaint(new Color(150,250, 187));
        g2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
        //g2D.drawArc(-50,50,300,300,0,90);

        CubicCurve2D cubic = new CubicCurve2D.Double(0,230,80,90,130,220,80,190);
        g2D.draw(cubic);
    }

}
```

This is the code of the frame

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Test extends JFrame implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{

    GraphicsDemo graphicDemo = new GraphicsDemo();

    int x, y;
    String str="";
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
        str = "Mouse Pressed";
        System.out.println("Coordinates of x: " + x + " , coordinates of y :" +y);
        repaint();
    }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
        str = "Mouse Released";
        repaint();
    }
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
        str = "Mouse Clicked";
        repaint();
    }
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
    {
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
        str = "Mouse Entered";
        repaint();
    }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
    {
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
        str = "Mouse Exited";
        repaint();
    }
    // override MouseMotionListener two abstract methods
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
    {
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
        str = "Mouse Moved";
        repaint();
    }
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
    {
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
        str = "Mouse dragged";
        repaint();
    }


    public Test()
    {

        this.setSize(420,420);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.add(graphicDemo);

        this.setVisible(true);
        this.addMouseListener(this);
        this.addMouseMotionListener(this);

    }

    public static void main(String[] a){
        new Test();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would find that difficult to to do with a mouse.  But that is beside the point.  Ideally, if you had a stylus you could draw the outline of the shape and then fill it in.  The Polygon class which implements Shape might be of use.  Frankly, when I see assignments like this I sometimes wonder if the taken approach is what the instructor intended.

Comment: You could also do g2D.fill(cubic) which may achieve the same effect. You would need to fine tune how the curve is fully created to get a smooth transition. But it would be easier than trying to gradually increase the stoke width.  Another possibility is to draw the image in the panel and then trace the pattern, storing the points.